# Is there any better way to use ratios?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series, forecasting

I am looking to predict the number of cars that will be parked in my 100-car capacity lot over the next seven days. To price the rental accordingly, I am analyzing the reservations from the past seven days and how they ultimately played out for each day. By using this data, I can determine the expected demand for each day. For instance, if I had 15 reservations on the fifth day seven days ago and final reservation for that day was 60, and now have 25 reservations for the 5th day in future, I can assume that the fifth day has increased in demand by a fraction of 25/15 and my future demand is 25*60/15 = 100.

The problem in this case is sometime my model predict more than 100 reservations despite the fact that my capacity is 100 for each day. Is there better way to scale and project the demand, I don’t wish to use a hard limit of 100 in the code?

Code below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

# Historical data
historical_data = {
    '18-Feb-23': (35, 38),
    '19-Feb-23': (40, 50),
    '20-Feb-23': (35, 50),
    '21-Feb-23': (28, 50),
    '22-Feb-23': (15, 65),
    '23-Feb-23': (10, 54),
    '24-Feb-23': (3, 70)
}

# Future data
future_data = {
    '25-Feb-23': (40, None),
    '26-Feb-23': (35, None),
    '27-Feb-23': (28, None),
    '28-Feb-23': (20, None),
    '1-Mar-23': (25, None),
    '2-Mar-23': (3, None),
    '3-Mar-23': (1, None)
}

# Calculate expected demand for each day
for date in future_data:
    # Get the corresponding date seven days ago
    past_date = (datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%b-%y') - timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%d-%b-%y')
    
    # Calculate the fraction of increase in demand from past to future
    if past_date in historical_data:
        past_reservations = historical_data[past_date][0]
        past_final_reservations = historical_data[past_date][1]
        future_reservations = future_data[date][0]
        fraction_increase = future_reservations / past_reservations
    else:
        # If past data is not available, assume no change in demand
        fraction_increase = 1.0
    
    # Calculate the expected final reservations for the future date
    if fraction_increase > 0:
        expected_final_reservations = int(round(past_final_reservations * fraction_increase))
    else:
        expected_final_reservations = past_final_reservations
    
    future_data[date] = (future_data[date][0], expected_final_reservations)

# Print the predictions
for date in future_data:
    print(f"{date}: Expected final reservations = {future_data[date][1]}")
```

Comment: I would make the capacity part of the historical data. That way you can calculate the occupancy rate instead. This will matter because if everyone knows your parking lot is always full, they are much more likely to make a reservation in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid providing your full capacity information (directly or indirectly) to the model?

Comment: It looks to me that you would fare much better with a more traditional ML technique than hard-coding the model to get information only on ratio from specific few (one?) data point.

Comment: @user13744439 Feast your eyes on the [SciKit documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html)

Comment: If you don't want to use a ML model you may find better results by looking at the fraction of your car park that is unreserved - that is, if the reservations went from 20 to 70 that is a change in the unreserved fraction from 80/100 to 30/100, or a reduction to 3/8 the number of unreserved spaces. As a fractional reduction in unused space will never reduce the unused space below 0 you will never predict reservations as above 100% usage. I would also suggest using more that 7 days historic data though, this is very little.

Comment: Probably this is a question better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) since your problem is not about how to write the program but on the analysis/statistical approach.

Comment: IIUC, you are trying to predict demand. So, why would it be a problem to hard-limit it to 100 or just let it go over that number? It makes sense: you would expect more demand for reservations than the ones you can allocate,  and therefore you'll have to reject some clients. This is indeed a realistic scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1/ You could try using a log scale instead of 'pure' ratios, that would smooth out towards 100 and that would only go above 100 when more than 100 people reserve (should be impossible.)

2/ Your data doesn't seem to be adapted to ratios the way you are using them (it looks like less people reserve, more people come.) Therefore I would recommend using two functions, which is close to using ratios. And finding out how many people to expect thanks with the other. Here is an example: (it plots the data so you can better understand what it does)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from math import exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np

# Historical data
historical_data = {
    '18-Feb-23': (35, 38),
    '19-Feb-23': (40, 50),
    '20-Feb-23': (35, 50),
    '21-Feb-23': (28, 50),
    '22-Feb-23': (15, 65),
    '23-Feb-23': (10, 54),
    '24-Feb-23': (3, 70)
}
Y1 = []
Y2 = []
#1 : finding out how to the customers behave & vizualizing it
for i in historical_data:
    Y1.append(historical_data[i][0])
    Y2.append(historical_data[i][1])
print(Y1,Y2)
X = [datetime.strptime(d,'%d-%b-%y').date() for d in historical_data]
print(X)
a1, b1 = np.polyfit([i for i in range(len(historical_data))], Y1, 1)
a2, b2 = np.polyfit([i for i in range(len(historical_data))], Y2, 1)
print(float(a1),float(b1))

pl.grid()
pl.plot(X,[float(a1)*i+float(b1) for i in range(len(historical_data))],'g-')
pl.plot(X,[float(a2)*i+float(b2) for i in range(len(historical_data))],'r-')
pl.plot(X,Y1,'g+')
pl.plot(X,Y2,'r+')
pl.show()

#changing X and Y axis
#X : reserved
#Y : come
def expecting(a1,b1,a2,b2,val):
    i = (val-float(b1))/float(a1) #solved the equation val = a1 * i + b1
    return float(a2)*i+float(b2)
X = [float(a1)*i+float(b1) for i in range(-10,10)]
Y = [float(a2)*i+float(b2) for i in range(-10,10)]
pl.plot(X,Y)
pl.show()
reserved = 30 #testing a value
expected = expecting(a1,b1,a2,b2,reserved)
print(expected)
#You can finish finding the values for the 'future data'
```

Good thing about this model : doesn't go above 100, and it works better with data provided.

Bad thing about this model: goes up to 70 and only makes sense if less than 40 people reserve (always the case with your examples.)

You could use kind of the same logic with other types of function (exponential, log, parabola...) depending on the other data you have and change the parameters to get it to fit.

Probably not the answer you were expecting, but hope it helps/gives you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you provide the capacity limit for the predictions, you can calculate the increase in  demand then use neural network to predict the demand as the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

# data
historical_data = {
    '18-Feb-23': (35, 38),
    '19-Feb-23': (40, 50),
    '20-Feb-23': (35, 50),
    '21-Feb-23': (28, 50),
    '22-Feb-23': (15, 65),
    '23-Feb-23': (10, 54),
    '24-Feb-23': (3, 70)
}

# calculate the increase in demand for each day
increase_in_demand = {}
for day, (reservations, final_count) in historical_data.items():
    increase_in_demand[day] = (final_count - reservations) / reservations

# Sequential model
model = Sequential()

# hidden layer with 10 units
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(1,)))

# output layer of NN with a sigmoid activation function
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'sgd')

# generates training data
X = np.array(list(increase_in_demand.values())).reshape((-1, 1))
y = np.array(list(historical_data.values()))[:, 1] / 100

# train with 100 iterations
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)

# future demand
future_data = {
    '25-Feb-23': (25,),
    '26-Feb-23': (30,),
    '27-Feb-23': (20,),
    '28-Feb-23': (10,),
    '01-Mar-23': (5,),
    '02-Mar-23': (2,),
    '03-Mar-23': (1,)
}

for day, (reservations,) in future_data.items():
    predicted_increase_in_demand = model.predict(np.array([[reservations / 100]]))[0][0]
    predicted_final_count = reservations + reservations * predicted_increase_in_demand
    print(f"Expected demand for {day}: {predicted_final_count:.0f}")
```

Output:

```
Expected demand for 25-Feb-23: 37
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 69ms/step
Expected demand for 26-Feb-23: 45
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 46ms/step
Expected demand for 27-Feb-23: 30
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 65ms/step
Expected demand for 28-Feb-23: 15
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 56ms/step
Expected demand for 01-Mar-23: 7
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 70ms/step
Expected demand for 02-Mar-23: 3
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step
Expected demand for 03-Mar-23: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a beautiful machine learning task.**

What you are doing is a beautiful heuristic to estimate the actual demand on a certain day. And that is fine, and probably gives you pretty good estimates already.

So before you are doing anything else, your next two steps should be:

1. Log the error of your estimates over time
2. Start logging the history of your demand (this data can be used to improve your heuristic / model of your demand system).

What you are actually trying to solve is to find an equation `f` that takes an input `x` here your reservations of the day, the reservations of last week rl, and the actual demand of last week yl) and map it to an estimation `y'`.

```
f(x) = y'
```

The simplest model would be to follow a linear equation and setting parameters `a` and `b`:

```
y' = a*x + b
```

This might seem familiar as this is exactly what you are doing:

```
a = x*(yl/rl)
b = 0
```

So this is the moment where you should take a step back, check your data and find the proper constants that fit the system you are trying to model and not based on some heuristic or intuitive idea you got from your perceived pattern between reservations and real demand - once you logged enough data, this will become easier and easier.

To make this more intuitive, I will estimate a model for workdays (days 1-5) - same could be done for weekends, and by only considering the reservations of a current day (the other information will be implicitly captured in the determined parameters `a` and `b`). The beauty of this is, that with each day that passes, you can refit your parameters and improve your model, to the current reality.

[image: easy fitting of a linear model]

So after tuning the parameters `a = -0.45` and `b = 65` you can predict future demand by applying this equation. Error is calculated as absolute difference between the estimation and the in hindsight measured real demand. The plot shows the estimated demand over the real demand (so for an optimal model, we would expect all points as close to the angle bisecting). You already can see that your model won't be able to be perfect for all data samples you have, when this error is not acceptable any longer, and the more data you are collecting, then you can start increasing the complexity of your model by adding parameters, e.g. by using a quadratic function instead of a linear one. This is done in the following as a further example.

[image: Quadratic model]

You can see that we could further improve the model as we are able to fit the reservations to the real demand easier as we have more degrees of freedom. However in case of doubt stick to your easier model, as a model with more complexity has a harder time generalizing to unseen data (the data you actually care that your model performs well on). You can for example see the extreme influence of your single data point where 15 reservations map to 65 demand - our linear model had a hard time modelling this, whereas the quadratic function fits it more optimal, which introduces an anomaly into your data. Saying this, worry not, the more data you will use to fit your parameters the less prone you will be to single outliers.

To give you some way to tell whether what I did makes sense. Here are the estimations on your future data:

[image: Future data predictions]

**Take it further**

- Probably your input of current reservations, and the current day is a little sparse as you might see fluctuations with respect to seasonal changes (weather, holidays) and others. So adding this information might help you to further improve your predictions.
- When redetermining your parameters you could also use some sort of sliding window approach (you currently do a 1 week window) including only data of e.g. the last year.
- Determining the parameters of more complex models is what is usually done with machine learning approaches and there are python libraries readily available for such tasks, if you want to deepen your knowledge I would recommend trying this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series